# Как передать аргументы в функцию main()

Tags: linux, golang

На c++ при создании функции можно было делать так `int main(int argc, char** argv)`, следовательно при запуске с терминала можно передать аргументы. При компиляции в `GoLang` пишет, что нельзя функции main иметь аргументы.
Как передать аргументы приложению на golang?

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments

Comment: или следующая статья :) https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags для полноценной поддержки флажков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргументы командной строки можно получить через из массива [os.Args](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables)

Так же можно воспользоваться пакетом [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) - для разбора аргументов вида --name=value